# How to properly set constrains for Auto layout for horizontal image views?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, autolayout, interface-builder

I am experiencing an issue with auto layout. More specifically, I am confused by how Auto Layout works when you have a rather complex(or maybe compact) layout. I never even succeed once when I tried to do a horizontal layout. For example, I tried to set two labels horizontally in storyboard before, no matter what I do, it's hot mess when checking it on an actual device.

So this time, my nightmare comes again. The screenshot here is the view I set up in the storyboard. I am using auto layout, so I must add constrains, what I did first is add a top space constrain for the first image view(top left), and it told me views are ambiguous. That doesn't seem right, because in circumstances like these, Xcode always tell me the image view needs a x position. But this time it's "ambiguous". And I tried many things, it didn't workout anyway. I gave up setting up manually, instead I ask the Xcode to do it for me, I tapped "reset to suggested constrains", and then set equal width and height, and then set the image views to 1:1 aspect radio. But when previewing, it's still a hot mess.

So apparently, neither me nor Xcode could set up the layout behaved just as expected. That's why I come here and ask you guys, let's me break it down for you about my concerns:
1. What constrains should I set for all the image views?
2. What constrains should I set for "topic"?
3. What constrains should I set for the label (description below the topic)?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can also use `UIStackView`s for layouts like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you start

> I am using auto layout, so I must add constrains, what I did first is
>   add a top space constrain for the first image view(top left), and it
>   told me views are ambiguous.

So when you set the top and left, your view knows x and y but it still doesn't know the width and height it needs to set for yourself. Which is what you should have done as the next step. Figure out a way so that constraints can make out what the height and width would be. A general example would give a bottom and right, fixed width and height and so on which can be n number of cases.

> set equal width and height, and then set the image views to 1:1 aspect
>   radio

You have set the constraints equal widths and height and some aspect ratio. At this point the image Views still don't know what there width or height would be as you never told any of the views that how much they should expand themselves.

At a certain point while setting the constraints for your views you need to make sure atleast one view knows how much it should expand and contract so that other views then can play around that.

Now lets tell you how you can fix this problem:

1. Set Equal widths and heights and 1:1 aspect ratio.
2. Stick all of the ImageViews with a top.
3. Give lefts and rights to the views near the margins that would be the ImageViews on the left and the right
4. Set the verticle and horizontal centres.
5. Set bottom and right constraint for the top left one and top and left for the bottom right one.

Now you should have all the constraints set and good to go as the rest of the ImageViews will infer themselves from the constraints you have added.